# Can php code be hidden?

Tags: php, html, parsing, adobe, muse

This is definitely a weird question, but here it goes:

I'm building a widget for Adobe Muse. The Adobe Muse software does not understand php so it displays it in the software as pure html.

PHP, however, can be added to a website and uploaded to the server. The server (if configured correctly) can parse the html as php.

So, when this is placed onto the Adobe Muse page:

```
<?php $ecwid_store_id = 1003; include('http://d3k8mi85fypo0h.cloudfront.net/ecwid_ajax_indexing.php');
  echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' .$ecwid_title. '"/>';
  echo '<meta name="fragment" content="!" />';
  echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' .$ecwid_canonical. '" />';
  echo '<meta name="description" content="' .$ecwid_description. '"/>';
?>
```

It displays in Muse like this

[image]

Is there any way of hiding the unparsed php while it is in Muse?

Comment: *can parse the html as php* I think you mean it the other way around right, *right*?

Comment: weird answer - don't upload php to a server that does not parse php

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, i did. thanks for catching that!